# setTimeout is returning a non-relevant decimal

Tags: javascript

I'm building a frogger style game. When the player reaches the top of the board (this.y == -25) the players position is reset (this.x // this.y) and the players score is incremented (this.points++).

Initally it was written:

```
class Hero {
    constructor() {
        this.points = 0;
    }
}

if (this.y == -25) {
   this.points++;
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.x = 202;
      this.y = 390;
      pointCount.innerHTML = (this.points);
   }, 100);
}
```

This incremented the pointCount by 7, So I attempted to correct it by writing:

```
if (this.y == -25) {
   this.points++;
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.x = 202;
      this.y = 390;
      pointCount.innerHTML = (this.points / 7);
   }, 100);
}
```

But now every once in awhile (not every time and seemingly random) it will increment the point by 0.85714.

Any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: Presumably, this code is typically getting called 7 times when you expect it to only be called once. When does this code get called?

Comment: Did you debug your code? 6/7 = .0857142.....

Comment: Your `if (this.y == -25) {...}` code is outside your class. Is it meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your function is being called 7 times and sometimes it is being called 6 times. Dividing the points by 7 is not a dependable fix. You could set a flag to make sure that the scoring code is only being called once.

```
let canScore = true;
if (this.y == -25 && canScore ) {
    canScore = false;
    this.points++;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.x = 202;
        this.y = 390;
        pointCount.innerHTML = (this.points);
        canScore = true;
    }, 100);
}
```